# In MongoDB, how do you retrieve a set of results where Field X is greater than Field Y by Value N?

Tags: database, mongodb, expression, robo3t

I'm trying to query my local MongoDB for documents where Field X is greater than Field Y by Value N (in this case, Value N = 0.25).

I currently have:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').find({ $expr: { $gt: [ "$field1" , "$field2" ] }}).sort({"dateAdded" : -1})
```

But this only returns results where field1 is greater than field2. I need field1 to be greater than field2 by 0.25.

I can't find this in the documentation anywhere, i'm sure i'm missing something easy...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create an expression that calculates the difference first and then you can do the greater than comparison.

Take for instance this query which uses the **[`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/)** operator to get the difference:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').find(
    { "$expr": { 
        "$gt": [ 
            { "$subtract": ["$field1", "$field2"] },
            0.25
        ] 
    }}
).sort({"dateAdded" : -1})
```

Comment: Thanks @chridam. I realised I had some issues with field formatting in my collection which was impacting my ability to verify this; namely some of my values had a Type of "String", which rendered $subtract unusable. Now I've rectified those issues, this works great.